# SceneKit avoid lighting on specific node

Tags: objective-c, macos, scenekit, light

In SceneKit I'm building a node made of lines to draw the XYZ axes at the center of the scene, like in Cinema4D.

[image: cinema4D]

I would like these 3 nodes not to participate to the global lighting and be viewable even if the light is dark / inexistent / too strong. In the picture below you can see that the Z axis appears too heavily lighten and can't be seen.

[image: my software]

Is there a way to stop a node participating to the scene's lighting, like with category masks for physics?

In this case, how would the node be lighten in order for it to appear anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SCNLight` has a `categoryBitMask` property. This lets you choose which nodes are affected by the light (Although this is ignored for ambient lights). You could have 2 light source categories, one for your main scene, and another that only affects your lines.

Here is a simple example with 2 nodes, each lit with a different colour light:

```
struct LightType {
    static let light1:Int = 0x1 << 1
    static let light2:Int = 0x1 << 2
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/scene.scn")!

        let lightNode1 = SCNNode()
        lightNode1.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode1.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode1.light!.color = UIColor.yellow
        lightNode1.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        lightNode1.light!.categoryBitMask = LightType.light1
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode1)

        let lightNode2 = SCNNode()
        lightNode2.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode2.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode2.light!.color = UIColor.red
        lightNode2.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        lightNode2.light!.categoryBitMask = LightType.light2
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode2)

        let sphere1 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sphere1", recursively: true)!
        sphere1.categoryBitMask = LightType.light1
        let sphere2 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sphere2", recursively: true)!
        sphere2.categoryBitMask = LightType.light2

        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig in it right now! Would you have a piece of code? :-)

Comment: @BenoîtLahoz I've added a quick example.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: categoryBitMask does not work on iOS 14.4. There are threads on Apple dev forum stating that it had been broken in iOS 12.

Answer (score 9):

I think it would be much easier to set the material's lightning model to constant.

```
yourNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
```